# SSRS reporting expressiong converting

Tags: reporting-services

If Usage > 0 And Tnd > 0 Then
                Return Math.Round((Tnd / Usage) * 100, 2)
            Else
                Return 0
            End If

please convert this it in SSRS expression

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
    `=IIF(Usage > 0 And Tnd > 0, Round((Tnd/Usage)*100,2), 0 )`